# [ NOT SOLVE] issue with list model list.removeAllElements java swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

i m using java swing and i want to make search box same as google so i used texfiels and Jlist and values added into it from database where List is setvisible(false) at start of program and it become visible(true) when data entered into JlistModel.

i will simulate program using JOptionpane.showMesssageDialoge i found bug at RemoveAllElement

my source code is ,

```
    TMSearch=new JTextField();
    TMSearch.setBounds(200,220,350,30);
    add(TMSearch);
    TMSearch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
        {

        String QueryValue;
            if(ke.getKeyChar()== '\b' )
            {
                QueryValue=TMSearch.getText();



            }
            else    
            {
                QueryValue=TMSearch.getText()+ke.getKeyChar();


            }
            if(ke.getKeyChar()== '\b' && TMSearch.getText().length() == 0 )
            {
            BMReset.doClick();
            }   

    try     
        {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/medi","root","");

            if(con==null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR");
            }

      MListModel.removeAllElements();   
            ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from medicine where cname like ? or mname like ?");
            ps.setString(1,QueryValue.concat("%"));
            ps.setString(2,QueryValue.concat("%"));


            rs=ps.executeQuery();


            while(rs.next())
        {           

                    int mid=rs.getInt("mid");
                    String  cname=rs.getString("cname");
                    String mname=rs.getString("mname");
                    float price=rs.getFloat("price");
                    String date=rs.getString("exp_date");
                    int mpunit=rs.getInt("mpunit");
                    int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                    String temp;
                    temp=mid+"  "+cname+"  "+mname+"  "+price+"  "+date+"  "+mpunit+"  "+quantity;

                    MListModel.addElement(temp);
                    MListPane.setVisible(true); 



    ListFlag=1;
        }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }   




        }
    });
```

Comment: Unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).
2. Learn and use Java naming conventions. Java variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.
3. Don't use empty {} catch blocks. Display the Exception so you have an idea what the problem is.
4. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using a DocumentListener to listener for changes in the text field. See [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.
5. Don't use a JList. A JTable is better for displaying data in columns. Check out the table of contents from the above tutorial links I have given you. You will find a section on `How to Use Tables`.

I suggest you keep easy access to the Swing tutorial since it contains all the Swing basics.

Comment: yes. i am beginner so i don't know much of effective java programming. thanks for your valuable information.